# Sending Sensor Data from Nodemcu ESP32 and Firebase

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to send sensor data from nodemcu ESP32 to firebase.
When using the basic example shown below it worked fine, and also when viewing the sensor data without sending it to firebase.
https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP32/tree/master/examples/Basic

However when I tried to edit the code a bit and send my sensor's data, I get an error, I would appreciate any help, code, and error attached.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseESP32.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include "WiFi.h"


#define DHTPIN 27     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321
#define FIREBASE_HOST "trial-2c3ea.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "Eu706797Vy2zOEDp3Bc9e4T9GZVAVwTyoxshl9Am"
#define WIFI_SSID "saadon 1"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "0547258525"


//Define FirebaseESP32 data object
FirebaseData firebaseData;

FirebaseJson json;
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
const int oneWireBus = 2;   
OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
const int Analog_channel_pin= 15;
double Soil_Moisture = 0;
double Soil_Moisture_analog = 0;
String path = "/Test";

void printResult(FirebaseData &data);

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  sensors.begin();
  dht.begin();
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();



  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);



}

void loop() {
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 
  float temperatureC = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Soil_Moisture_analog = analogRead(Analog_channel_pin);
  Soil_Moisture = (0.00531*exp(0.29*(Soil_Moisture_analog*0.006+1.0265)))*100;

      if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Air Temp" + t))
    {
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      printResult(firebaseData);
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println();
    }

  if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Air Humidity" + h))
    {
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      printResult(firebaseData);
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println();
    }

    if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Soil Temperature" + temperatureC))
    {
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      printResult(firebaseData);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println();
    }

    if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Soil Moisture" + Soil_Moisture))
    {
      Serial.println("PASSED");
      printResult(firebaseData);
      Serial.println();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("FAILED");
      Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
      Serial.println();
    }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Error:

firebasecode:74:65: error: no matching function for call to 'FirebaseESP32::setFloat(FirebaseData&, StringSumHelper&)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setFloat` method takes three parameters:

```
  bool setFloat(FirebaseData &dataObj, const String &path, float floatValue);
```

From https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP32/blob/master/src/FirebaseESP32.h#L1084

So the path and value are separate parameters. Change the calls to `setFloat` to look like:

```
      if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Air Temp", t))
```

Comment: Thank you!! that solved it, but now I have a different problem, for some reason, it sends the temperature data but not the humidity data, any idea why?
The new code looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

This is the new code which for some reason does not send the air humidity data, only air temp, the soil temp and moisture works fine.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseESP32.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include "WiFi.h"


#define DHTPIN 27     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321
#define FIREBASE_HOST "trial-2c3ea.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "Eu706797Vy2zOEDp3Bc9e4T9GZVAVwTyoxshl9Am"
#define WIFI_SSID "saadon 1"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "0547258525"

FirebaseData firebaseData;

FirebaseJson json;

void printResult(FirebaseData &data);
//Define FirebaseESP32 data object




DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
const int oneWireBus = 2;   
OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
const int Analog_channel_pin= 32;
double Soil_Moisture = 0;
double Soil_Moisture_analog = 0;
String path = "/Test";


void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  sensors.begin();
  dht.begin();
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);


}

void loop() {
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 
  float temperatureC = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Soil_Moisture_analog = analogRead(Analog_channel_pin);
  Soil_Moisture = (0.00531*exp(0.29*(Soil_Moisture_analog*0.006+1.0265)))*100;

    Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Air Humidity", h);
    Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Air Temp", t);
    Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Soil Temperature", temperatureC);
    Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, path + "/Soil Moisture", Soil_Moisture);
 delay(5000);


}
```

Comment: This belongs in a separate question. The problem (and solution) will be entirely different from the original question. I can't see anything obviously wrong so preferably after you have some additional investigation/research.

I recommend you try printing out the humidity data and send hard coded humidity values to Firebase. This will help isolate where the problem is.